# Initial state "checked" for a custom checkable element in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-selector

I'm trying to build a checklist using a custom "Checkable" element. I'm able to display the list, check the checkbox (it's an ImageView) and save the state of each checkboxes in a DataBase.

Unfortunately, when I open a checklist, **I would want to initialize the checklist with some checked checkboxes**, but I can't. It doesn't work.

---

## Screenshots

Here is my screen when I open a checklist :

[image: android screen that display a checklist with every checkbox unchecked]

**Legend:** android screen that display a checklist with every checkbox unchecked

I used the method .setEnabled(true/false) to show visually there are differents states (for debug purpose).

Basically, when I tick a checkbox as a user, it look like this :

[image: android screen with a checkbox checked]

**Legend:** android screen with a checkbox checked

---

## Hierarchy

- src
- - com.checkit.app (package)
- - - CheckableLinearLayout.java
- - - TasksActivity.java
- - - TasksAdapter.java <= (I think the problem can be solved somewhere in this file)
- - - [...]
- res
- - drawable
- - - ic_hideable_item.xml
- - drawable-mdpi
- - - btn_check_off.png
- - - btn_check_on.png
- - - [...]
- - layout
- - - activity_tasks.xml
- - - task_items.xml
- - - [...]

---

## Code

### TasksAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * @author tony
 *
 */
public class TasksAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    /* ************************************* properties */

    // list of items
    private ArrayList<Task> mItemsList;

    // context
    private Context mContext;

    // a single task
    private Task taskItem = null;


    /* ************************************* contructors */

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param item
     */
    public TasksAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Task> pTasksItems) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItemsList = pTasksItems;
    }


    /* ************************************* override methods */

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItemsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Task getItem(int position) {
        return mItemsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    /**
     * Display the view of the task of a checklist
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // if we access for the first time : we have to user LayoutInflater
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_items, null);
        }

        // get the font size (from the SharedPreferences)
        String fontSizeSetting = MainActivity.getmFontSize();

        // set the text on the tasks
        //CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task);
        com.checkit.app.CheckableLinearLayout checkboxGlobal = (com.checkit.app.CheckableLinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskGlobalCheckbox);
        ImageView checkboxImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskImageCheckbox);
        TextView checkboxTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_text);

        // get the Task
        taskItem = (Task) mItemsList.get(position);

        // is this task done ?
        // .getIsTick values are 0 (false) or 1 (true)
        if (taskItem.getIsTick() == 1) {
            // the task is done, so tick the checkbox
            Log.d("TEST", "TasksAdapter getView() is getIsTick");

            // TODO I should do something here to tick the box. But what should I do ??
            checkboxGlobal.setChecked(true); // I go to the method, but this do nothing ??
            checkboxGlobal.setEnabled(true); // just to show that it's well working


            // INFO : below are a lot of tries, but no one works properly
            //StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
            //Drawable drawable = convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_hideable_item);
            //drawable.setState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked});
            //states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked}, drawable);
            //states.setState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked});
            //checkboxImg.setImageDrawable(states);
            //checkboxImg.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        } else {
            // the task is undone, so untick the checkbox
            Log.d("TEST", "TasksAdapter getView() is not getIsTick");

            checkboxGlobal.setChecked(false);
            checkboxGlobal.setEnabled(false);

        }

        // set the text on the TextView
        checkboxTxt.setText(taskItem.getName());

        // change the font size
        checkboxTxt.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(fontSizeSetting));

        // return the view
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

### CheckableLinearLayout.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * File based on the official example (cf. http://developer.android.com/samples/CustomChoiceList/index.html )
 * 
 * This is a simple wrapper for {@link android.widget.LinearLayout} that implements the {@link android.widget.Checkable}
 * interface by keeping an internal 'checked' state flag.
 * <p>
 * This can be used as the root view for a custom list item layout for
 * {@link android.widget.AbsListView} elements with a
 * {@link android.widget.AbsListView#setChoiceMode(int) choiceMode} set.
 */
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {


    /* ************************************* properties */

    // android state for "checked"
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

    // default state : FALSE = every checkbox are untick
    private boolean mChecked = false;


    /* ************************************* contructors */

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    /* ************************************* override methods */

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);

        if (isChecked()) {
            Log.d("TEST ", "CheckableLinearLayout.onCreateDrawableState("+extraSpace+") (isChecked TRUE)");
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }

        return drawableState;
    }


    /* ************************************* aspects methods */

    /**
     * Is this checked ?
     */
    public boolean isChecked() {
        Log.d("TEST ", "CheckableLinearLayout.isChecked()");
        return mChecked;
    }


    /**
     * Set the item as checked (if it's not yet)
     */
    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        Log.d("TEST ", "CheckableLinearLayout.setChecked()");

        // close if it's still the same state
        if (b == mChecked) {
            return;
        }

        Log.d("TEST ", "CheckableLinearLayout.setChecked() inside");

        // modify the state
        mChecked = b;
        // refresh the drawable state
        refreshDrawableState();
    }


    /**
     * Toggle current state
     */
    public void toggle() {
        Log.d("TEST ", "CheckableLinearLayout.toggle()");
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}
```

### ic_hideable_item.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" 
        />
    <item 
        android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" 
        />
</selector>
```

### activity_tasks.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listTasks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

### task_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.checkit.app.CheckableLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/taskGlobalCheckbox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/taskImageCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hideable_item"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_alt_checkbox"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/task_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        />

</com.checkit.app.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

---

## More

Here are some things I want to say :

- `checkboxGlobal.setEnabled(true);` works perfecty, as we can see in the screenshot (the grey title). But `checkboxGlobal.setChecked(true);` seems to have no effect (?)
- Once, I tried `Drawable drawable = convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_hideable_item);` followed by `checkboxImg.setImageDrawable(states);`. It work perfectly to initialize the checkbox with a checked checkbox, but then it's not possible to untick the box.

**Edit 2014-03-12 :** My code is based on an official code sample from the "Android Developers" website (cf. project "CustomChoiceList", available here : http://developer.android.com/samples/CustomChoiceList/index.html).

**Edit 2014-03-13 :** Remove unecessary code, for readability purpose

Thanks in advance for your help. Feel free to ask if you want more code.
Sincerely,
Tony

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. It doesn't seems to be very effective, but it works.
My answer is based on the code of **DroidBender**.

For those who may be interested, here is the code of `.getView()` method inside TasksAdapter.java :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // if we access for the first time : we have to user LayoutInflater
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_items, null);
    }

    // get the font size (from the SharedPreferences)
    String fontSizeSetting = MainActivity.getmFontSize();

    // set the text on the tasks
    checkboxGlobal = (com.checkit.app.CheckableLinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskGlobalCheckbox);
    checkboxImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskImageCheckbox);
    checkboxTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_text);

    // get the Task ( "final" <= very important)
    final Task taskItemFinal = (Task) mItemsList.get(position);

    // is the task done ?
    boolean isTick = (taskItemFinal.getIsTick() == 1 ? true : false );

    // init
    Drawable drawable = null;

    // is this task done ?
    if (isTick) {
        // the task is done, so tick the checkbox
        drawable = convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_check_on);
    } else {
        // the task is undone, so untick the checkbox
        drawable = convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_check_off);
    }
    // set the initial drawable
    checkboxImg.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    // click event on the checkbox
    checkboxGlobal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // is the checkbox ticked ?
            boolean isTick = (taskItemFinal.getIsTick() == 1 ? true : false );

            Drawable drawable = null;

            // set a different drawable depending to the state
            if (isTick) {
                drawable = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_check_off);
            } else {
                drawable = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_check_on);
            }

            // set the drawable to the element
            checkboxImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskImageCheckbox);
            checkboxImg.setImageDrawable(drawable);

            // toggle 
            taskItemFinal.toggle();

            // Open the connection
            TaskDAO taskDao = new TaskDAO(v.getContext());
            taskDao.open();

            // update the data
            taskDao.update(taskItemFinal);

            // set to false
            return false;
        }
    });

    // set the text on the TextView
    checkboxTxt.setText(taskItemFinal.getName());

    // change the font size
    checkboxTxt.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(fontSizeSetting));

    // return the view
    return convertView;
}
```

The tips consists to use a final variable called `taskItemFinal` and to used it inside the `.taskItemFinal()` method. Then I change the drawable by myself.
In this case, you have to remove the `.setOnItemClickListener`inside the TasksActivity.java file (as I was doing before to save the state).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `selector` as followed:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" 
        />
    <item 
        android:state_selected="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" 
        />
</selector>
```

Inside your `getView(..)` of your `Adapter` (I have used some non-existing getters & setters for explanation purposes):

```
 // code code code
 checkboxImg.setSelected(taskItem.isTicked());
 checkboxImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view){
          taskItem.setTick(!taskItem.isTicked());
          notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

 });
 // code code code
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the method `.checkboxImg()` doesn't exists for `checkboxImg` since it's an ImageView. However, this method can be called on `checkboxGlobal`, but it seems to have no effect (at least visually).

Comment: Updated my answer with appropriate calls.

Comment: Thanks again.
Knowing that the imageView use `android:duplicateParentState="true"`, it's possible to directly use `checkboxGlobal` instead of `checkboxImg`.
You have good ideas to try to solve this problem, unfortunately your code doesn't works either since it's a multiple choice checklist (cf. `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`).
When I use your code the selector doesn't even show the tick image when an item is checked/pressed/selected on the ListView.
Do you have another idea ? :)
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have tried a similar approach, and discover this example is also wrong because `taskItem` in this code sample will be the last item in the ListView. So, even if the event works, this will tick the last checkbox of the list.